# How to prevent onedrive from downloading my whole onedrive if I only want to download a small file

Tags: onedrive

https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/onedrive-sorry-your-changes-could-not-be-saved.622318/

I tried to instruct onedrive to sync only one file and I get this error.

I do not want to download my whole onedrive.

However, onedrive automatically download the whole thing. And when I tried to stop I got that message.

> Sorry your changes could not be saved. Wait till all the files are
> synced first.

But I don't want to download the whole files and I have wasted so many hours trying to fix it. Logout first. Login first.

Comment: Turn OFF One Drive Sync and just use it as a Cloud tool. It is up to you to determine how best to use it.

Comment: Please don't make us follow a link to understand your question. You did not give us the error at any point in the question itself.

Comment: I posted the content of the error message.

Finally onedrive did it right. But when I come back the next day they turn on all folders again. Which is very disgusting.

Comment: Besides, the question is clear enough. I do NOT want to sync my whole content of onedrive. Just one folder. How do I do that?

And why the hell Microsoft automatically set up my one drive and SYNC the whole folder without confirming to me first?